# Updating images data from angular v14 to Asp.Net Core 6.0 Rest Api

Tags: asp.net, angular, typescript, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I'm sending product model data from angular to rest API by using FormData, in that product data I've an images array. When I received that product in rest API I'm accessing images data by using `Request.Form.Files` then by using memory stream I send it to DB and when I want to get that data in angular I convert this images data into `base64` string.

Now I want to update data using the same product object by which I post new product data, I can update the name property but I don't know how to update images data which is a complex property.

Below is my code.

**Image Model**

```
import { SafeUrl } from "@angular/platform-browser";
export interface Image {
    id? : number,
    base64Image?: string,
    file : File,
    url?: SafeUrl
}
```

```
export class PostProductComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() newProduct: Product;
  @Input() editedProduct: Product;
  productForm: FormGroup;
  files: File[] = [];

  ngOnInit(): void {
   this.productForm = this.fb.group({
      id: [0],
      name: [''],
      images: this.fb.group({
        id: [0],
        file: [null]
      })
    });
  }
uploadImage(event: any) {
    this.files = event.target.files;
    const fileEvent = event.target.files[0];
        const imageHandle: Image = {
          file: fileEvent,
          url: this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(
            window.URL.createObjectURL(fileEvent)
          )
        }
    this.product.images.push(imageHandle);
}
removeImages(i: number) {
    this.product.images.splice(i, 1);
  }
addProduct() {
    this.mapFormValuesToProdModel();
    const productFormData = this.prepareFormData(this.product);
    this.prodService.postProduct(productFormData).subscribe(add => {
      console.log(add);
    });
prepareFormData(productData: Product): FormData {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('name', productData.name);
    
    for (let i = 0; i < productData.images.length; i++) {
      formData.append('file', productData.images[i].file, productData.images[i].file.name);
    }
    return formData;
  }
mapFormValuesToProdModel() {
    this.product.name = this.productForm.value.name;
  } 
}
**For Edit & Update Product Data**
**Here i'm getting & assigning editedProduct data to product input property**
onEditClick() {
    this.prodsComponent.emitData.subscribe((editedProduct) => {
       this.product = editedProduct;
       this.editProduct(this.product);
      }
    });
  }
**Here by this method i'm displaying edited data on productForm,i can update name but how i have to update images data? **
editProduct(product: Product) {
    this.productForm.patchValue({
      name: product.name,
    });
    for (const image of product.images) {
      image.url = 'data:image/jpg;base64,' + image.base64Image;
    }
```

**Template file code for images**

```
<div formGroupName="images">
   <div class="form-group">
     <div class="input-group">
        <input type="file" name="file" (change)="uploadImage($event)" multiple="multiple" />
     </div>
   </div>
  <div>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let file of product.images; let i = index;">
      <span (click)="removeImages(i)">x</span>
        <img [src]="file.url">
    </ng-container>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your images property in ProductForm is a `FormControl` instead of a `FormArray`  where you speak of a product being able to have multiple images. This is confusing.

Furthermore you can access the images FormControl like this:

```
this.productForm.controls.images
```

which gives a reference to a `FormControl` (currently; where this must be a `FormArray` I suppose). This way you can loop throug the images `FormArray` and set the update properties (id; base64String) accordingly. Or simply replace the complete value of the images property with a new `FormArray`.

Comment: Youp by using my above code i can select multiple images and posted them as a product object to rest API,i think abt FormArray its used for dynamically generated FormControl at run time,so i think i don't need to generate it, that's why i am using FormGroup,by this code ```for (const image of product.images) {
      image.url = 'data:image/jpg;base64,' + image.base64Image;
    }``` i can display on screen all images of that edited product now i just want to update that images data that i can send it by using formData object to rest api,If i am wrong then plz let me know.

Comment: We are on a different page unfortunately. `for (const image of product.images) {   image.url = 'data:image/jpg;base64,' + image.base64Image;}` There you should update the form controls in the images `FormArray`.

Comment: Youp can you show me the code or refer me to any link where i can see the code

Comment: Read the answer. This should give you some pointers to find your way . Make sure you get a reference to the images property which must be something like this `this.productForm.controls.images` and then iterate it to replace update image id/name/base64 or replace the images property completely with a new FormArray with the updated values.

Comment: @JuniorDev did you make some progress? If this helped you out please mark the answer as so (check mark it)

Comment: I'm still working on it, i'm trying to solve it in another way as above i posted my code, after that i will try to solve it as you told me then i will mark your answer & i will write some explanation too that it can be helpful for others and i'm very thankful to you that you trying to help me.